# binding control visibility to a toggle button's ischecked property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

**EDIT**: it appears this was just VisualStudio somehow getting confused. It accepted it just fine after restarting. I'm not seeing a way to close the question though.

I have a window with two controls: a togglebutton and a textbox. I want the togglebutton to control the visibility of the textbox, namely, show the textbox when the togglebutton's ischecked property is true, and collapse the textbox when it is false (with an initial ischecked status of false).

Based on the information I've been able to find, it seems like the following simple XAML should work:

```
<Window
  x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IsCheckedVisibilityConverter"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ShowTextBox" Content="Show the TextBox" IsChecked="False"/>
    <TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ShowTextBox, Converter={StaticResource IsCheckedVisibilityConverter}}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

However, I am unable to compile and run this as I receive the error:

```
The TypeConverter for "IValueConverter" does not support converting from a string.
```

with a blue squiqqly underline underneath the portion [Visibility="{Binding].

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong, but I've spent a few hours trying to find information as to why it's not working, and all I can find are examples showing this being the more-or-less correct way to do it. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm relatively new to C#/WPF/XAML, so I'm toying around with things to get a better feel for it all. If there's a control that's better suited for this task, I'm interested to know about it, but I'm more interested in how to get this working so I can better understand what's happening (or rather, why it's not working).

Thank you.

Comment: Looks good to me. There are no errors in your xaml.

Comment: Have you build it? Beause sometimes it keeps on jammering until you build.

Comment: I did. Everything worked.

Comment: Everything works fine in my computer. Vs2012 & .net4.5

Comment: I guess it was just VisualStudio getting confused somewhere. I closed it and just now came back to it, and now it's not giving me the error. Thank you everyone for trying to help me with this.